# How to send image file to server - Kotlin using Fuel

Tags: android, kotlin, upload

I have a problem when attempting to use Fuel to send image to my server.
I am trying to use the `Fuel.upload` method.

```
        Fuel.upload(urlfile).source { request, url ->
            File(photopath)
        }.responseString { request, response, result ->

        }
```

the image is like : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/fr.tais.riodi/files/Pictures/MyPicture4945313277123614993.jpg

```
$target_dir = "images/";
$target_file_name = $target_dir .basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$response = array();

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if (isset($_FILES["file"])) 
{
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file_name)) 
   {
     $success = true;
     $message = "Successfully Uploaded";
   }
   else 
   {
      $success = false;
      $message = "Error while uploading";
   }
}
else 
{
      $success = false;
      $message = "Required Field Missing";
}
$response["success"] = $success;
$response["message"] = $message;
echo json_encode($response);
```

I tried to find an example of this operation. Have you an examples or an idea?

Thanks all

Comment: Can you post details of the error you receive.